# Strange Warnings/Erros with Code Contracts and Interface inheritance

Tags: inheritance, c#-4.0, interface, code-contracts

as the topic subject, I've encountered strage Warnings/Erros with Code Contracts and Interface.
Here my scenario

Primary Interface

```
[ContractClass(typeof(DTOInfoContract))]
public interface IDTOInfo
{
    int ID { get; }
    string Description { get; }        
    string LinkText { get; }
    string Title { get; }

    void DTOInit(int id, string title, string descr, string linkText);
}
```

Secondary Interfaces

```
[ContractClass(typeof(DTONewsContract))]
public interface IDTONews : IDTOInfo
{    
}

[ContractClass(typeof(DTOPromoContract))]
public interface IDTOPromo : IDTOInfo
{                
    string Photo { get; }

    void DTOPromoInit(int id, string title, string descr, string linkText, string Photo);
```

And then my Contracts

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IDTOInfo))]
public abstract class DTOInfoContract : IDTOInfo
{
    int IDTOInfo.ID
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0, "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(int); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.Description
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.LinkText
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.Title
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    void IDTOInfo.DTOInit(int id, string title, string descr, string linkText)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(id > 0, "id has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title), "titolo has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descr), "descr has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText), "linkText has no valid value");
    }
}


}


[ContractClassFor(typeof(IDTONews))]
public abstract class DTONewsContract : IDTONews
{
    int IDTOInfo.ID
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0, "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(int); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.Description
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.linkText
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.Title
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    void IDTOInfo.DTOInit(int id, string title, string descr, string linkText)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(id > 0, "id has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title), "title has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descr), "descr has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText), "linkText has no valid value");
    }
}


[ContractClassFor(typeof(IDTOPromo))]
public abstract class DTOPromoContract : IDTOPromo
{        
    string IDTOPromo.Photo
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }        

    void IDTOPromo.DTOPromoInit(int id, string title, string descr, string linkText, string photo)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(id > 0, "id has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title), "title has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descr), "descr has no valid value");                  
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText), "linkText has no valid value");
    }

    int IDTOInfo.ID
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0, "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(int); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.Description
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.LinkText
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    string IDTOInfo.Title
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Returned value is out of Range"); return default(string); }
    }

    void IDTOInfo.DTOInit(int id, string title, string descr, string linkText)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(id > 0, "id has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title), "title has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descr), "descr has no valid value");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText), "linkText has no valid value");
    }
}
```

With this situation I've only some Warnings like the following

```
warning CC1076: Contract class DTOPromoContract cannot define contract for method IDTOInfo.get_ID as its original definition is not in type IDTOPromo. Define the contract on type IDTOInfo instead.
```

But, if I try to delete the IDTOInfo method and properties in the IDTONews and IDTOPromo contract classes the errors was, for example, the following

```
Error   40 'DTOPromoContract' does not implement the member of interface 'IDTOInfo.Description'
```

Is it a strange situation, isn't it?
Is there a solution to have the best combination of Code Contracts and Interface with the previous scenario?

Thank You!

Comment: I can't try right now but what happens when you use  `public abstract class DTOPromoContract : DTOInfoContract, IDTOPromo` ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Thank you for the answer, I've tried your solution but now the warning is "warning CC1066: Class 'DTOPromoContract' is annotated as being the contract for the interface 'IDTOPromo' and cannot have an explicit base class other than System.Object." I think it is right :-)

Answer (score 1):

Contract classes should only specify behaviour for the interface that they're attached to, and not any base interfaces.

So, in `DTOPromoContract` and `DTONewsContract`, all methods which are inherited from `IDTOInfo` should be `abstract`. (All interface contract classes should be `abstract` as well.)

Comment: maybe I don't understand, do you mean something like this? In DTONewsContract:  abstract int IDTOInfo.ID { get.... } ?? It isn't a valid modifier for that class. Please, can you explain your answer? Thank you!

Comment: You have to implement the entire interface of course including base interfaces, otherwise C# isn't happy. But for contracts, you only want to specify contracts for the toplevel interface you are actually annotating. For the inherited interface methods, just let the C# compiler implement them automatically throwing NotImplemented.

Comment: @ManuelFahndrich: You shouldn't need to implement the base interfaces at all, since your Contract class will be abstract.

Comment: @Porges, by implementing, I meant have a declaration that makes the C# compiler happy. So yes, an abstract declaration for inherited interface members is fine too.

Comment: @ManuelFahndrich: Cool, just clarifying that :)